# Show message if no shipping zone is avialable

Tags: php, woocommerce

I am using Woocommerce as shop system. 
I want to display a additional message to the default one, if no shipping zone is available for the given address.

Here is what i want to show:

```
echo "<div class='shipping_notice_germany_checkout'>Leider sind unsere Produkte noch <b>nicht Flächendeckend in Deutschland verfügbar</b>. Bitte <a href='#deutschland-versand-popup' class='open-popup-link'> kontaktieren Sie uns</a>, um die perfekte Lösung für Sie zu finden.</div>";
```

the hook where I want it to show is this one: cfw_checkout_after_shipping_methods

so I added this function to my functions.php:

```
function my_custom_wc_free_shipping_notice2() {
echo "<div class='shipping_notice_germany_checkout'>Leider sind unsere Produkte noch <b>nicht Flächendeckend in Deutschland verfügbar</b>. Bitte <a href='#deutschland-versand-popup' class='open-popup-link'> kontaktieren Sie uns</a>, um die perfekte Lösung für Sie zu finden.</div>";
}
add_action( 'cfw_checkout_after_shipping_methods', 'my_custom_wc_free_shipping_notice2' );
```

However I am missing the if part of the function, to only show it if no other shipping methods are available.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: So which is your problem?

Comment: Message now is showing always. I want it only to show, if no shipping classes are available. (for example if the zip code is not valid for shipping). So it should NOT show, when free shipping or flat rate is availbale.

Comment: you can use `$_POST['post_code']` and check if is avaible nothing else `echo`.

Comment: can you explain this further - sorry i am new to php! Thanks!

Comment: Note that cfw_checkout_after_shipping_methods is a custom hook that doesn't exit in WooCommerce by default, so with the provided code and information in your question, nobody can guess things and help you with a useful answer.